# 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters when decoding

Tags: python

Code:

```
try:
        json_data = urllib.request.Request(query)
        print(type(json_data))
        with urllib.request.urlopen(json_data) as data:
            data1 = str(data.read().decode('utf-8'))
        print(type(data1))
except Exception as e:
    print ("! Sorry, something went wrong:")
    print ("! Error: %s"%e)
    sys.exit(1)

statuses = json.loads(data1).get("statuses")
texts = [tweet.get("text") for tweet in statuses]

for text in texts:
print (text,"\n")
```

Error prints:

```
   'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 227-227: 
      Non-BMP character not supported in Tk.
```

Is there a  way to ignore the error and proceed or to replace the unsupported code with a replacement character?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... Why are you decoding the bytes and then passing it to `str()`?

Comment: I need to use json.load(), which requires data1 to be string and not byte

Comment: But then why would you decode it?

Comment: Because I get this error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: I'd edit the code in the main question for a clearer picture

Comment: Issue fixed! Thanks anyways

Comment: If you didn't catch the error, you would get a useful stacktrace...